# How to Put Start Date and End Date as parameters from jsp page to jasper report

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports

[image]

**Purchase.jsp**

```
<form action="view2.jsp" method="post">
<select name="category">
<option value="">Make a selection</option>
<option value="company">company</option>
<option value="institution">institution</option>
<option value="hospital">hospital</option>
<option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
<select name="status">
<option value="">Select Status</option>
<option value="close">Close</option>
<option value="open">Open</option>
<option value="pending">Pending</option>
</select>
&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
<select name="day">
                            <option>DD</option>
                            <option>01</option>
                            <option>02</option>
                            <option>03</option>
                            <option>04</option>
                            <option>05</option>
                            <option>06</option>
                            <option>07</option>
                            <option>08</option>
                            <option>09</option>
                            <option>10</option>
                            <option>11</option>
                            <option>12</option>
                            <option>13</option>
                            <option>14</option>
                            <option>15</option>
                            <option>16</option>
                            <option>17</option>
                            <option>18</option>
                            <option>19</option>
                            <option>20</option>
                            <option>21</option>
                            <option>22</option>
                            <option>23</option>
                            <option>24</option>
                            <option>25</option>
                            <option>26</option>
                            <option>27</option>
                            <option>28</option>
                            <option>29</option>
                            <option>30</option>
                            <option>31</option>
</select>
<select name="month">
<option>MM</option>
                            <option>01</option>
                            <option>02</option>
                            <option>03</option>
                            <option>04</option>
                            <option>05</option>
                            <option>06</option>
                            <option>07</option>
                            <option>08</option>
                            <option>09</option>
                            <option>10</option>
                            <option>11</option>
                            <option>12</option>
</select>
<select name="year">
 <option>YYYY</option>
                            <option>2012</option>
                            <option>2013</option>
                            <option>2014</option>
                            <option>2015</option>
                            <option>2016</option>
                            <option>2017</option>
                            <option>2018</option>
                            <option>2019</option>
                            <option>2020</option>
                            <option>2021</option>
                            <option>2022</option>
                            <option>2023</option>
                            <option>2024</option>
                            <option>2025</option>
                            <option>2026</option>
</select>
&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
<select name="day1">
                            <option>DD</option>
                            <option>01</option>
                            <option>02</option>
                            <option>03</option>
                            <option>04</option>
                            <option>05</option>
                            <option>06</option>
                            <option>07</option>
                            <option>08</option>
                            <option>09</option>
                            <option>10</option>
                            <option>11</option>
                            <option>12</option>
                            <option>13</option>
                            <option>14</option>
                            <option>15</option>
                            <option>16</option>
                            <option>17</option>
                            <option>18</option>
                            <option>19</option>
                            <option>20</option>
                            <option>21</option>
                            <option>22</option>
                            <option>23</option>
                            <option>24</option>
                            <option>25</option>
                            <option>26</option>
                            <option>27</option>
                            <option>28</option>
                            <option>29</option>
                            <option>30</option>
                            <option>31</option>
</select>
<select name="month1">
                            <option>MM</option>
                            <option>01</option>
                            <option>02</option>
                            <option>03</option>
                            <option>04</option>
                            <option>05</option>
                            <option>06</option>
                            <option>07</option>
                            <option>08</option>
                            <option>09</option>
                            <option>10</option>
                            <option>11</option>
                            <option>12</option>
</select>
<select name="year1">
                            <option>year</option>
                            <option>2012</option>
                            <option>2013</option>
                            <option>2014</option>
                            <option>2015</option>
                            <option>2016</option>
                            <option>2017</option>
                            <option>2018</option>
                            <option>2019</option>
                            <option>2020</option>
                            <option>2021</option>
                            <option>2022</option>
                            <option>2023</option>
                            <option>2024</option>
                            <option>2025</option>
                            <option>2026</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search"/>
</form>
```

**view2.jsp**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setAction(nPage){

        document.forms[0].action = nPage;
    }
</script>
<body>
<%
String category=request.getParameter("category");
session.setAttribute("cat",category);
String status=request.getParameter("status");
session.setAttribute("sta",status);
String day=request.getParameter("day");
session.setAttribute("da",day);
String month=request.getParameter("month");
session.setAttribute("mon",month);
String year=request.getParameter("year");
session.setAttribute("yea",year);
String day1=request.getParameter("day1");
session.setAttribute("da1",day1);
String month1=request.getParameter("month1");
session.setAttribute("mon1",month1);
String year1=request.getParameter("year1");
session.setAttribute("yea1",year1);
%>
<select onchange="setAction(this.value)">
<option value=''> Make a selection </option>
<option value='PDF_LEAD.jsp'> PDF</option>
<option value='XLS_LEAD.jsp'> XLS </option>
<option value='DOC_LEAD.jsp'> DOC </option>
<option value='XLSX_LEAD.jsp'> XLSX </option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search"/>
</body>
```

**PDF_LEAD.jsp**

```
<body>
<% 
Connection conn = null;
String cate=(String)session.getAttribute("cat");
String stat=(String)session.getAttribute("sta");
String dayy=(String)session.getAttribute("da");
String monthh=(String)session.getAttribute("mon");
String yearr=(String)session.getAttribute("yea");
String dayy1=(String)session.getAttribute("da1");
String monthh1=(String)session.getAttribute("mon1");
String yearr1=(String)session.getAttribute("yea1");
try 
{ 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/marketing_database","root","root");
    String jrxmlFile ="D:/dev/tools/jasper files/report10.jrxml";
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(jrxmlFile));
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);

    System.out.println("Compiling Report Designs");
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

    System.out.println("Creating JasperPrint Object");
    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("complan",comp);
    map.put("search",sear);
    map.put("category",cate);
    map.put("status",stat);
    map.put("day",dayy);
    map.put("month",monthh);
    map.put("year",yearr);
    map.put("day1",dayy1);
    map.put("month1",monthh1);
    map.put("year1",yearr1);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,map,conn);
    byte bytes[] = new byte[10000]; 
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    ByteArrayOutputStream PDFStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint); 
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, PDFStream); 
    exporter.exportReport(); 
    System.out.println("Size of byte array:"+PDFStream.size()); 
    bytes = PDFStream.toByteArray(); 
    response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 1"); 
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 2"); 
    PDFStream.close(); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 3"); 

    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream(); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 4"); 
    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length); 
    outputStream.flush(); 
    outputStream.close(); 

}
catch(Exception e) 
{e.printStackTrace();} 

%>
</body>
```

**report10.jrxml**

```
<parameter name="category" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="search" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="status" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from lead where Status='$P!{status}' and category ='$P!{category}' and Company_Name like '$P!{search}%']]>
    </queryString>
```

Here i have "Start Date" and "End Date".I have passed the "Category" parameter and "status" parameter but how to pass "Dates" parameter from jsp to jasper report?? I have used select tag names as "day","month","year" for "Start Date" and have used select tag names as "day1","month1","year1" for "End Date" as (mentioned in Purchase.jsp)below.My second question is, in MYSQL database i didnt have a column named as "Start Date" and "End Date". The columns i have in my database are

> (id,Name,Email,Company_Name,Contact_Person,Address,Phone,Company_Email,Review,Lead_Date,Lead_Details,Lead_Value,Followup_Date,Status,Category).

So how to put "Start Date" and "End Date" in my "where" clause of MYSQL Database

Comment: @Peter Friberg Help Me! please

Comment: How about pass "Start Date" and "End Date" as String type, and use `STR_TO_DATE`?

Comment: Can you write the code once about how to use STR_TO_DATE

Comment: I'm not usually using MySQL, so I don't know much about MySQL.
`WHERE STR_TO_DATE('$P!{start_date}', '%d-%m-%Y') >= some_date1 and STR_TO_DATE('$P!{end_date}', '%d-%m-%Y') <= some_date2`

Please googling "mysql str_to_date where clause".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer above would solve your problem related to the question (in fact I upvote it), but since I see that you struggle (2nd question) generating the sql inside of jasper report -I will suggest another metod

Generating the query in jsp and passing the whole query to jasper report.

To do this you need to use concat metodo that can be subject to "sql injection" but i suggest this anyway since:

1. Simplifing the task
2. You are already using it in jasper report, hence $P!{} not $P
3. The damage someone could do is only viewing some records in your report.

The only thing I do suggest is that you escape the ' char to not break query if some user search on es goo'gle. This you can do by this simple code:

```
userInput.replaceAll("\\'", "''")
```

So doing this within your jsp (PDF_LEAD.jsp) you can create your sql something like this

```
String sql = "select * from lead where Status='" + stat.replaceAll("\\'", "''") + "'";
if (sear!=null && searc.trim().length()>0){
  sql+=" AND Company_Name like '" + searc.replaceAll("\\'", "''") + "%'";
}
```

etc etc arriving to your date after your `if` you add something like this.

```
sql+="DATE(the_name_of_you_date_column)>='" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "'";
```

Note the MySQL date format is `yyyy-MM-dd`

Once you finshed creating your query ouput it to the `System.out.println(sql);`, that way you can test your query in MySQL Workbench (without the report), it will help you to understand if something is wrong...

The last thing you need to do is pass the query to jasper report:

```
 HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
 map.put("sql",sql);
```

Add the parameter to your .jrxml

```
<parameter name="sql" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

And change the query string to:

```
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[$P!{sql}]]>
</queryString>
```

Hope this will help and narrow down your problem on how to create the correct sql. (Don't copy and past my code check that it's correct I have written it by not knowing exactly your parameters and checking syntax)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following snippet to convert the string to date in your jsp code.

```
int year = 2003;
int month = 12;
int day = 12;

String date = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
java.util.Date utilDate = null;

try {
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
  utilDate = formatter.parse(date);
  System.out.println("utilDate:" + utilDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
  System.out.println(e.toString());
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and pass the date as parameter to the jasper report.

Then, in jrxml you can declare the parameter with java.util.Date type as follows,

```
<parameter name="startDate" class="java.util.Date">
    <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
</parameter>
```

Then you can use this date directly in your MySQL query.

Comment: Its showing "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date"

Comment: Have you changed the parameter class?

Comment: yeah i have changed parameter class as "java.util.Date"

Comment: My sql query is select * from lead where Category='$P!{category}' and Status='$P!{status}' and Lead_Date>=$P!{startdate} and Lead_Date<=$P{end date}

Comment: My jrxml   is                                                <parameter name="category" class="java.lang.String">
<parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
</parameter>
 <parameter name="status" class="java.lang.String">
<parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
</parameter>
 <parameter name="startdate" class="java.util.Date">
<parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
</parameter>
 <parameter name="end date" class="java.util.Date">
<parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
</parameter>

Comment: Except the parameter name "end date" have one space I don't find any issue here. Please check the exception trace to find which line of the jrxml this error "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date" comes. And please check whether you have dragged the parameter you have created before changing the class type.

Comment: Its surprising to me that i didnt create any parameter "start Date" and "end Date" in jasper report its working but when i created parameters in jasper report its not working

Comment: Actually what i did was i wrote a query like this.  select * from lead where Category=$P{category} and Status=$P{status}.  and i used "session attributes" to store the value that is selected in drop down menu and i mapped the values that are previously stored

Comment: This is what i did        String cate=(String)session.getAttribute("cat");
String stat=(String)session.getAttribute("sta");
String dayy=(String)session.getAttribute("da");
String monthh=(String)session.getAttribute("mon");
String yearr=(String)session.getAttribute("yea");
String startdate=dayy + "/" + monthh + "/" + yearr;
String dayy1=(String)session.getAttribute("da1");
String monthh1=(String)session.getAttribute("mon1");
String yearr1=(String)session.getAttribute("yea1");
String enddate=dayy1 + "/" + monthh1 + "/" +yearr1;

Comment: HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
 map.put("category",cate);
 map.put("status",stat);
 map.put("day",dayy);
 map.put("month",monthh);
 map.put("year",yearr);
 map.put("day1",dayy1);
 map.put("month1",monthh1);
 map.put("year1",yearr1);
 map.put("startdate",startdate);
 map.put("enddate",enddate);

Comment: Ok. Then you passed a string. So you have to have the parameter startdate with class as java.lang.String. And use the following in the query `DATE_FORMAT(field,'%d/%m/%Y') eq $P!{start_date}` if you want to check the equality. If you want to check between condition in sql you have to convert the string to Date Object as I have given in the example and use it in the query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92133/discussion-between-chitti-oneterahertz-and-karthick).